# How to dynamically release Spring Pageable PageSize (Limit)?

Tags: spring

I use Spring Pageable in Querydsl and no problem.

However, internal rules sometimes require "unlimited".

Sometimes you simply need to query all of the data.

If you don't specify a current Pageable value, a default size is forced.

Can I make this default size something like unlimited?

Or is there a special value that means page size that requires all data?

Comment: If you don't need pages, don't use `Pageable` but directly execute the query.

Comment: Sometimes I need it and sometimes I don't.

Of course I could create a new query without pageable , but it would be easier if I could turn off the default.
(It's terrible to create all new Query created with Pageable!)

Comment: Why would you need to create a new query? You already have the method, copy it and return a `List` and remove the `Pageable` argument (or if sorting is important, keep the `Sort`).

Comment: Depending on the version of Spring Data you are on, you could try using `Pageable.unpaged` for no paging. However that would also include no sorting information (and it isn't clear from your question if you want to preserve that).

Comment: As mentioned, I am using querydsl, so I am using pageable.getOffset() and pageable.getPageSize() in offset and limit, respectively.

I don't know how to apply the Pageable.unpaged you mentioned,

What I want is not to do individual work for every query.

Currently, I need to be able to release the limit in bulk without specifically modifying all the queries I have written.

Comment: THen don't use offset/pagesize if you know you don't need it. You cannot do it without not modifying your code. Also you are making a lot of assumptions on what people know about QueryDSL and how you are using it (so next time when asking a question show code/configuration as well!).

Comment: I thought it was a simple question. My thoughts were short.

Thank you for your help.